# highcharts.js column/bar overlap (datetime Xaxis)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have trouble to make my Highchart work properly for my usage.

I have a datetime axis with "column/bar" display and multiple series. The problem is that the series "overlap" on each other, making it complicated to read (the mouseover is complicated because series hide each other).

You can see what it does here : https://jsfiddle.net/okbguc03/3/

I just would like to prevent overlapping (i guess highchart would have to "stretch time" in order to display the bar on side of each other).

I've tryed playing with "padding" and "pointwidth" and i've disabled stacking, but it doesn't help (and i need pointwidth because the bars are very thin).

```
"plotOptions": {
"column": {
  "stacking": "null",
   pointWidth : 10
 },
```

Thanks in advance for your help =)

Comment: Suggestion would be to use the line chart instead of bar or column chart. As the time interval is irregular it would be hard to define the column or bar size. If they are too close it would lead to overlap again.

Comment: The data for Person 1 and Person 2 is the main reason for overlap.

Comment: It's normal when you are using `datetime` axis type. Points are overlapped, because the interval between them (it's too small). If you will try to change the position of overlapped points, it would breaks the logic of the chart.

Comment: Ok so the main solution would be to use the line chart i guess.

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that you can't force highcharts to disable overlap and the line chart is the best display for this kind of data